# How to install dependencies -liberty？

Tags: boost

I'm compiling a code with "/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -liberty", I can't find anything related to -liberty, how can I solve this dependency problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Hul.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu: sudo apt install libiberty-dev